# How to find mAh rating of battery for my project?

Tags: batteries, energy, nodemcu

I am using a NodeMCU ESP8266 for my project.

The datasheet says it consumes 170 mA in active mode, and approximately 10 milliamperes in sleep mode.

In my project, the NodeMCU runs 1 minute in active and the rest 59 minutes in sleep mode.

How much energy will it consume in 24 hours?

How do I select a battery accordingly?

Comment: I might be a good idea to first do your own current measurements. 170mA continuously when active sounds like way too much. I know the ESP8266 itself can do much better than 10mA when in sleep mode, so there are probably some power hungry components on the NodeMCU board.

Comment: This is a simple arithmetic problem. Where are you stuck with it?

Comment: What type of battery are you considering using?

Answer (score 5):

'M' is for mega = 1,000,000 Ah. You mean 'm' for milli. Capitals matter.

Similarly 'A' is for ampere or amp. If you're writing out the long version it's 'milliamp'.

Calculation:

$$ Average\ consumption = \frac {170m \times 1 + 10m \times 59} {60} = 12.6\ \text{mA}$$.

---

Pay attention to capitalisation of sentences, brand names, initialisations and electrical units, and also to punctuation. It makes a big difference to the readability and accuracy of your writing and how it will be perceived by your customers in working life.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, thanks for your edit but I rolled it back. I'm not using \$'m'\$ as an abbreviation for mA but rather as a multiplier for the current in preference to writing 0.170 and 0.010 A. In general I try to avoid writing units into equations as they get confused with variables but I did notice that you had correctly applied a space between the value and the units and used `\mathrm` to differentiate.

Comment: It's your answer, but I think that usage is inconsistent with SI standards. See NIST Pub 811, section 7.10.1, and IEEE/ASTM SI 10-2016 , section 3.4.8.2 b).

Comment: "In general I try to avoid writing units into equations as they get confused with variables" – For what it's worth, when I see \$170 m\$, I wonder what this mysterious variable \$m\$ is, and I have to puzzle out what \$m\$ is supposed to mean, since your answer doesn't say what it means. On the other hand, when I see \$170 \ \mathrm{mA}\$, I instantly know that it means 170 milliamps. So if your goal is to avoid confusion, I have to say that the choice you've made is counterproductive.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Tanner. I'll consider it. Maybe the world isn't ready for this yet - "but your kids will love it!".